# Thymeleaf : 2 loops and an if statement inside a single element

Tags: thymeleaf

In thymeleaf, I have a for each loop like so:

```
<ul  class="days">  
  <li th:each="day : ${days}" th:text="${day}" >1</li>

</ul>
```

This successfully lists all of the strings in an array called `days` which is populated like ["1","2","3"..."31"] representing the days in a given month.

I also have an array of `items` which also contains days as strings.

Here is what I want to do in pseudo code but am struggling to figure out how to achieve it:

> For each day in `days`; For each day in `items` ; if `items.day` =
>   `days.day` then set `'class=active'` (bootstrap) and `th:text =days.day`
>
> else
>
> `th:text=days.day`

So if theres a day in `items` that matches a day in `days` then the `<li>` element is set to `class=active`  and make the `<li>` clickable with `href="/myurl"`. And either way the day from `days` is the `th:text` of the `<li>`.

Sorry if thats hard to understand, I tried to make it as clear as I could.

EDIT:
This is latest attempt:

```
<ul class="days">

    <li th:each="s : ${days}" th:with="found=${false}">
        <span th:each="item : ${items}" th:if="{$item.day == s}"> 
                <span th:text="${s}" th:classappend="active" th:href
                       th:with="${found} = true"></span>

        </span> 

        <span th:if="{$found == false}">
             <span th:text="${s}"></span>

        </span>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: If you can, you might find it cleaner/easier to do this on the backend, make day an object with .value (1,2,3,...) and ".isActive" based on the items array, then do a `<li th:class="${day.isActive} ? 'active'">`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with [conditional expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions). Simply write something like

```
<span th:text="${s}" th:classappend="${#lists.contains(items, s)}? 'active' : ''">
```

This code also uses #lists, a very useful feature of Thymeleaf.